# How do I set the value for an Invoice custom field using the QuickBooks V3 DataService?

Tags: api, quickbooks, custom-fields, invoice, dataservice

I am attempting to create new invoices in QuickBooks using the V3 API.  I have the invoice creation working perfectly, except I cannot set the values for the 3 custom fields.

I need a VB or C# resolution that utilizes the AnyIntuitObject property in this context.

Here is the code that I am attempting to implement:

```
Dim serviceContext As ServiceContext = getServiceContext(profile)
Dim invoiceDataService As New DataService(serviceContext)
Dim oInvoice As New Invoice()

oInvoice.DocNumber = "8675309"
oInvoice.TxnDate = DateTime.Today.Date
oInvoice.TxnDateSpecified = True
oInvoice.CustomerRef = New ReferenceType() With {.Value = "1885", .name = "QBT"}

Dim cField As New CustomField()
cField.DefinitionId = 1
cField.Name = "MyCustomFieldName"
cField.Type = CustomFieldTypeEnum.StringType
cField.AnyIntuitObject = New String() {"MyCustomFieldValue"}

oInvoice.CustomField = New CustomField() {cField}

Dim invLine As New Line()

invLine.Amount = 999.99D
invLine.AmountSpecified = True
invLine.DetailType = LineDetailTypeEnum.SalesItemLineDetail
invLine.DetailTypeSpecified = True

invLine.AnyIntuitObject = New SalesItemLineDetail With
{
    .ItemElementName = ItemChoiceType.UnitPrice,
    .AnyIntuitObject = 999.99D,
    .Qty = 1D,
    .ItemRef = New ReferenceType() With {.name = "Service", .Value = "529"}
}

oInvoice.Line = New Line() {invLine}

Dim invoiceAdded As Invoice = invoiceDataService.Add(Of Invoice)(oInvoice)
```

I have reviewed every thread I can find pertaining to custom fields and the API and still have not found a resolution.

Any help that can be provided would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved the issue by using the following:

```
Dim customFieldList As New List(Of CustomField)
Dim cField As New CustomField()
cField.DefinitionId = 2
cField.Name = "Week ending"
cField.Type = CustomFieldTypeEnum.StringType
cField.AnyIntuitObject = inv.WeekEnding.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")

customFieldList.Add(cField)

oInvoice.CustomField = customFieldList.ToArray
```